# Mutex for CUDA host code? boost::mutex no solution due to BOOST_COMPILER redefinition with nvcc

Tags: boost, cuda, mutex

Do anyone see a possiblity to synchronize operations in CUDA host code? With CUDA host code I mean the host code that is contained in your .cu-file and preprocessed by nvcc and then passed to cl.exe on windows for example.

Due to the unavoidable preprocessing of the host code by nvcc I cannot use my preferred implementation boost::mutex: If I include boost stuff I get an error of BOOST_COMPILER makro redefinition.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate your CUDA C code from the rest. Have the .cu files contain your kernels, device functions, kernel calls, etc. Make headers for the kernel calls and use those in your cpp files. This can also help reduce the compile time because compiling .cu files is slow.

Comment: I have already tried that, but there's another important request for my host-code: I do operations on a CUDA surface, which is static by nature and has to be declared in global scope. When I use it in a seperate .cpp / .hpp - file the cl.exe doesn't know how to handle it and the nvcc is missing it.